# lipo - input file must be a fat file when the -thin option is specified

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, bios, vmware-fusion, lipo

I am trying to extract somethinh from a UNIX Executable File (vmware-vmx).

When i try to execute `lipo vmware-vmx -thin i386 -output vmware_x64`, I'm getting an error

`input file (vmware-vmx) must be a fat file when the -thin option is specified`

What is it and how do i fix it?

Comment: Is the original file a fat binary? Try `file vmware-vmx`, and see what it lists.

Comment: vmware-vmx: setuid Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Comment: That's the problem, then: you can't extract the i386 version from a file that only contains a x86_64 version.

Comment: "lipo vmware-vmx -thin x86_64 -output vmware_x64" gives the same error